# Custom #define macro for unit testing

Tags: c, unit-testing

I have a function that is returning the condition of a macro, and for unit testing I want to be able to determine what this macros value is.

Currently I have,

```c
#define READ_PORT ReadingPortStatus(SOME_OTHER_CONDITION)

#ifdef UNIT_TEST
bool READ_PORT_flag_UT;
#endif

void ReturnPortCondition()
{
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
#undef READ_PORT
    if (READ_PORT_flag_UT)
    {
        #define READ_PORT 1
    }
    else
    {
        #define READ_PORT 0
    }
#endif

    if (READ_PORT)
    {
        return(GOOD_READ);
    }
    else
    {
        return(BAD_READ);
    }
}
```

And in my unit test file I would use it as follows,

```c
extern READ_PORT_flag_UT;

READ_PORT_flag_UT = true // Because I want ReturnPortCondition() to return true
bool result = ReturnPortCondition();
```

However, it is not working as I expect, it is only returning the last define of the port, which in this case is 0. the if else statements are not working in this context.

Comment: `#define` is a preprocessor directive, not something that happens at runtime. There is no "current value" of a macro at runtime.

Comment: `if (...) { #define READ_PORT 1 } else { #define READ_PORT 0 }` The preprocessor will see `#define READ_PORT 1` followed by `#define READ_PORT 0`. The compiler will see `if (...) { } else { }`

Comment: Macros are entirely compile time. You can't change a `#define` based on a runtime condition.

Comment: Is there a way for me to accomplish what I want to within testing, or is this a case ill just have to pass over?

Comment: The usual way to do unit/mock testing is to (keep the original macro) and just link to a stub version of `ReadingPortStatus` that is just `return READ_PORT_flag_UT`

Answer (score 2):

Macros are entirely compile time. You can't change a `#define` based on a runtime condition.

What you can do instead is re-define `READ_PORT` to be your `READ_PORT_flag_UT` variable instead of a function call. That way if `UNIT_TEST` is defined any use of `READ_PORT` will use that variable. If `UNIT_TEST` isn't defined `READ_PORT` will be the function call.

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
bool READ_PORT_flag_UT;
#define READ_PORT READ_PORT_flag_UT
#else
#define READ_PORT ReadingPortStatus(SOME_OTHER_CONDITION)
#endif

void ReturnPortCondition()
{
    if (READ_PORT)
    {
        return(GOOD_READ);
    }
    else
    {
        return(BAD_READ);
    }
}
```

Comment: will this mean that READ_PORT will always be the same condition throughout the execution of the program?

Comment: @ColinHarker If `UNIT_TEST` is defined when your program is compiled, `READ_PORT` will *always* be `READ_PORT_flag_UT`, which can have different values at runtime. If `UNIT_TEST` isn't defined when your program is compiled, `READ_PORT` will *always* be `ReadingPortStatus(SOME_OTHER_CONDITION)`, which may return different values at runtime.